# How to make a forward button to navigate through JavaFx browser and also a button that will open a list with all hyperlinks?

Tags: browser, javafx

now i've done a simple web browser using JavaFx. I've managed to do a backButton....but a forwardButton i did not succeed to do. Also, i had in mind a button that will open a list with all hyperlinks (or links) that were visited in JavaFx browser. How can i make the back button to work ? And how about a button to open a window with hiperlinks (or links) of last visited pages? (i had in mind a DefaultListModel and an ArrayList but i wan't your opinion about this). Thanks in advance ! :)

Here's my code:

```
    backButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {

            int sizeHistory = webEngine.getHistory().getEntries().size();
      if(sizeHistory>1)       {


          Entry entry = webEngine.getHistory().getEntries().get(sizeHistory-2); 

         webEngine.load(entry.getUrl());
        }
        }
    });

     forwardButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {

            int sizeHistory = webEngine.getHistory().getEntries().size();
      if(sizeHistory>1)       {


          Entry entry = webEngine.getHistory().getEntries().get(sizeHistory);
          System.out.println("URL hist.: " + entry.getUrl());
         webEngine.load(entry.getUrl());
        }
        }
    });
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your back and forward buttons. The value you compute as `sizeHistory` is just the total number of pages visited (and stored in the history). Surely the handlers should just be

```
backButton.setOnAction(e -> webEngine.getHistory().go(-1));
forwardButton.setOnAction(e -> webEngine.getHistory().go(1));
```

For the other part of your question, you can create a `ListView` that displays the entries in the history:

```
ListView<WebHistory.Entry> historyView = new ListView<>();
historyView.setItems(history.getEntries());
```

With just a little work you can have the cells in the list display the titles of the corresponding pages:

```
historyView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<WebHistory.Entry>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(WebHistory.Entry entry, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(entry, empty);
        textProperty().unbind();
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            textProperty().bind(entry.titleProperty());
        }
    }
});
```

and you can tie the selection to the current index of the history with a couple of listeners:

```
history.currentIndexProperty().addListener((obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
    if (newIndex.intValue() != historyView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()) {
        historyView.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(newIndex.intValue());
    }
});

historyView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue.intValue() != history.getCurrentIndex()) {
        history.go(newValue.intValue() - history.getCurrentIndex());
    }
});
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.web.WebHistory;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebBrowser extends Application {

    private TextField textField ;
    private WebView webView ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        webView = new WebView();

        webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                primaryStage.setTitle(webView.getEngine().getTitle());
                textField.setText(webView.getEngine().getLocation());
            }
        });

        textField = new TextField("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802248/");
        textField.setOnAction(e -> load());

        load();

        Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");
        clearButton.setOnAction(e -> webView.getEngine().loadContent(""));

        WebHistory history = webView.getEngine().getHistory() ;

        Button backButton =  new Button("Back");
        backButton.disableProperty().bind(history.currentIndexProperty().lessThanOrEqualTo(0));
        backButton.setOnAction(e -> 
                history.go(-1));

        Button forwardButton = new Button("Forward");
        forwardButton.disableProperty().bind(
                history.currentIndexProperty().greaterThanOrEqualTo(Bindings.size(history.getEntries()).subtract(1)));
        forwardButton.setOnAction(e -> 
                history.go(1));

        HBox controls = new HBox(10, textField, backButton, clearButton, forwardButton);
        HBox.setHgrow(textField, Priority.ALWAYS);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        ListView<WebHistory.Entry> historyView = new ListView<>();
        historyView.setItems(history.getEntries());
        historyView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<WebHistory.Entry>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(WebHistory.Entry entry, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(entry, empty);
                textProperty().unbind();
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    textProperty().bind(entry.titleProperty());
                }
            }
        });

        history.currentIndexProperty().addListener((obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
            if (newIndex.intValue() != historyView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()) {
                historyView.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(newIndex.intValue());
            }
        });

        historyView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue.intValue() != history.getCurrentIndex()) {
                history.go(newValue.intValue() - history.getCurrentIndex());
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(webView, controls, historyView, null, null);

        textField.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private void load() {
        String url = makeUrl(textField.getText()) ;
        webView.getEngine().load(url);
        textField.setText(url);
    }


    private String makeUrl(String text) {
        if (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+:.+", text)) {
            return text ;
        } else return "http://"+text ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great ! Thanks !